"Restrict Where This Project Can Be Run" setting altered when agent not available
I had jobs where the "Restrict where this project can be run" was set to a specific node.  During installation of security updates, this node failed and had to be rebuilt.  It was, and is operational.  But it appears that the jobs that had this setting (to use this node as that 'restricted' location) had the setting deleted; I've seen elsewhere that this might be due to this specific node being not available and in fact missing.  My google foo to find this in the documentation has failed.  Can someone point me towards the appropriate part of the docs that cover this situation?
